# Unable to populate Table with Ajax Json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am sending this valid JSON as a response from my webservice call

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        },
        {
            "id": 1234,
            "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        },
        {
            "id": 12345,
            "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        },
        {
            "id": 123456,
            "vendorName": "MahalakshmiCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        }
    ]
]
```

This is my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.2.46:8086/Poller/poll/initial',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (response) {
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.vendorName + '</td><td>' + item.item + '</td></tr>';
                });
                $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        });



    });


<table id="records_table" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>UID</th>
    </tr>
```

With this the result is looking like this in browser

[image]

I am editing my question

**Edited Part**

Due to the cross domain restrictions , i am forming my JSON into jsonp as shown below

This is my ajax jquery request

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.2.46:8086/Poller/poll/initial',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                      trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.vendorName + '</td><td>' + item.item + '</td></tr>';
                });
                $('#records_table').append(trHTML);

                doPoll();
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        });

    });
```

Due to the jsonCallback , its not forming a valid JSON response and i am getting undefined when forming the table 
IS there anyway i can from the valid JSON  response ??

```
jsonCallback([
    [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        },
        {
            "id": 1234,
            "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        },
        {
            "id": 12345,
            "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        },
        {
            "id": 123456,
            "vendorName": "MahalakshmiCounter",
            "item": "Chocltae"
        }
    ]
])
```

Comment: inspect response , i don't think it contains AN ARRAY

Comment: You should cut that screenshot in only 10 secs on pbrush. We appreciate.

Comment: i edited my answer, have a look at it, but you still have an issue because you have an array in an array, and you'r trying to access your objects in the first one (although it's in the second one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have one more `$.each()` loop:

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    $.each(item, function(_, o){
      trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.id + '</td><td>' + o.vendorName + '</td><td>' + o.item + '</td></tr>';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your data is an array in an array, and you consider it only as an array

try to do the same `each` loop on `response[0]` for example

**EDIT**

I'm not sure you can use jquery `each` on a JSON object, instead you should use :

```
for(var i in response) {
    response[i]; // do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be having another array in that result. Try to loop one more time, like this for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/yH942/1/

```
$.each(jsonResponse, function(key, array) {
$.each(array, function(k, object) {
    // your code goes here
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your object after receiving or use $.getJSON instead of $.ajax. You are trying to use a string as an object.

```
success: function (response) {
   response = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Comment: his datatype is `jsonp` so it will return JSON, not a string.